# Ambiguous Use of Subscript - only happens during archive

Tags: ios, swift

this used to work until i upgraded to xcode 7.3 a few days ago.  It compiles and runs fine up until I need to archive the project.  During the archive I get a "Ambiguous Use of Subscript" error on the second question mark?

```
if let address = placemark.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"]?[1]
{
//do something
}
```

Any idea on how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ambiguous Use of Subscript` means that the compiler could not infer which subscript you want to use. It looks like the type of `placemark.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"]` returns is unclear to the compiler.

Try breaking it up like:

```
let addressLines = placemark.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"] as? [String]

if let address = addressLines?[1]
{
//do something
}
```

I haven't tried this so I'm not 100% on the syntax. But this would force the type to be a string array which (I think) is what you're expecting to get back.